# WPF 4: Windows Forms Host, Crystal Reports Asynch

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

Is there a way to render WinForms controls like Crystal Reports Viewer asynch, or even in a different thread, without freezing the applicaton.
My problem is that, when I assign the report source property, the viewer tried to render the report and some reports run for so long and it freezes the whole app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be required.. looks the default behavior of both Crystal Reports 2010 Winforms and WPF viewers render the report asynchronously. They show a spinner while rendering instead of holding the UI thread. This way you UI, most of the times, still remains responsive.